# How to compute kubernetes memory usage with Grafana

Tags: kubernetes, grafana

I have  setup a new grafana board monitoring the memory usage of my Kubernetes nodes. I have build to metrics which I can monitor separately.

Total Memory for all nodes:

```
sum (machine_memory_bytes{kubernetes_io_hostname=~"^$Node$"}) by (kubernetes_io_hostname)
```

And the memory usage by nodes:

```
sum (container_memory_working_set_bytes{id="/",kubernetes_io_hostname=~"^$Node$"}) by (kubernetes_io_hostname)
```

Both metrics show the values I expect. But what I try to archive is the usage in percent.

```
 metric-1 / metric-2 * 100
```

Something like:

```
sum (container_memory_working_set_bytes{id="/",kubernetes_io_hostname=~"^$Node$"})  
/ 
sum (machine_memory_bytes{kubernetes_io_hostname=~"^$Node$"}) 
* 100
by (kubernetes_io_hostname)
```

But this did not work. Because the metric is now invalid. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think it's not possible to divide two times series to get the average. for that there are functions like "AsPercent" or if you are using Prometheus

sum(rate(container_memory_working_set_bytes{id="/",kubernetes_io_hostname=~"^$Node$"})[1m])  / sum (machine_memory_bytes{kubernetes_io_hostname=~"^$Node$"}) *100
by (kubernetes_io_hostname)

this Link could be helpful https://github.com/camilb/prometheus-kubernetes

Comment: I tried it, but now get the following error: 
"parse error at char 84: range specification must be preceded by a metric selector, but follows a *promql.Call instead"

Comment: Now I found the following solution: 

sum(container_memory_usage_bytes{id="/",kubernetes_io_hostname=~"^$Node$"}) by (kubernetes_io_hostname)/ on (kubernetes_io_hostname) machine_memory_bytes{kubernetes_io_hostname=~"^$Node$"}